# Open a file with Python with given name in a folder that change name

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.walk

I'm using Python 2.7.8

I want to open a file named 'data.html' in a folder/file structure like this

```
'C:\SVN\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\{54F35-586-4AC-895B-52B5CB5}\data.html'
```

My problem is that the folder:

```
\{54F35-586-4AC-895B-52B5CB5}
```

is changing names between execution of my python script. Rest of the file/folder  structure is static.

My python script for the moment look like this:

```
linkToHtmlReport = 'C:\SVN\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\{54F35-586-4AC-895B-52B5CB5}\data.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(linkToHtmlReport))
```

My question is how to open the file data.html when the folder "{54F35-586-4AC-895B-52B5CB5}" is changing name between run of script? Can I use os.walk for this?

Thx for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use glob to glob!

```
import glob
path = glob.glob("C:\SVN\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\*\data.html")[0]
```

I always used it from linux... but should also work on windows.
[glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) will return you a list of path that match that query. You can access position 0 if you are sure that there is always only one of them.

Anyway it's better if you check if the list is empty as follow:

```
import glob
pathList = glob.glob("C:\SVN\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\*\data.html")
if pathList:
    path = pathList[0]
```

Comment: Thx, It works :)! But how do you think about the: if pahList: path = pathList[0]? If I run that code it will just give me path == "C" even if pathList was ok

Comment: not sure again i understand your comment... did you remove the [0] at the end of the glob.glob instruction? If you do not then pathList[0] will contain the first character of the string... if you remove it then pathList will contain the list of all the found path... so the [0] is simply the first path that was found!

Comment: Ahh, I missed you have removed the "[0]" :)! Ok, thank you for helping out :)!